# Why is div row not working here?

Tags: html, division

I am trying to create a top header with HTML using div row. There should be one word on the left, and the other 3 words on the left; all within the row. However, result turns out to be all four words are on different rows stacked together. I can't find nothing wrong from my codes.

```
<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="row" style="background-color:orange; margin:-8px; margin-top:-20px">
<div class="col-md-1">
</div>
<div class="col-md-1">
  <h3>stark</h3>
</div>
<div class="col-md-6">
</div>
<div class="col-md-1">
  <h3>about</h3>
</div>
<div class="col-md-1">
  <h3>portfolio</h3>
</div>
<div class="col-md-1">
  <h3>contact</h3>
</div>
<div class="col-md-1">
</div>
```

Comment: Have you included bootstrap?

Comment: it worked for me..http://codepen.io/anon/pen/YpeJWd
as pointer by kk have you addedd bootstrap??

Comment: Yes, it works. Thanks ! I included the wrong bootstrap library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming from the classes you are using, you are using Bootstrap. Ensure the bootstrap css and javascript files are referenced. Your html seems to work properly in this fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/e29aju5c/

```
<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="row" style="background-color:orange; margin:-8px; margin-top:-20px">
<div class="col-md-1">
</div>
<div class="col-md-1">
  <h3>stark</h3>
</div>
<div class="col-md-6">
</div>
<div class="col-md-1">
  <h3>about</h3>
</div>
<div class="col-md-1">
  <h3>portfolio</h3>
</div>
<div class="col-md-1">
  <h3>contact</h3>
</div>
<div class="col-md-1">
</div>
```

You should have the following code (or the equivalent code pointing to your bootstrap files) somewhere on the page:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js">
```

Answer (score 1):

The Bootstrap .row class is defining a left and right margin of -15px.

But you overwrite this with your **margin: -8px;** and that's why the columns don't fit anymore into the row.

Remove **margin:-8px; margin-top:-20px** and it will work.